# Use command line to stream RTSP of IPCAM via VLC

Tags: 16.04, command-line, vlc, streaming

I use shell script to display IPCAMS.
for one set of cams I use **successfully**

```
cvlc -vvv --network-caching $cache rtsp://192.168.3.$port:554 --zoom $zoom
```

where `$port`,  `$cache` and `$zoom` are script parameters.

But, for the 2 commands below, streaming works only when using GUI and not command line.

In both cases, I contacted IPCAM's manufucturer to get the correct syntax.
I tried to alter to syntax of set one - with/without cvlc/vlc , zoom, cache, without any success.

1) `rtsp://admin:888888@192.168.6.21:10554/udp/av0_0`

2) `rtsp://192.168.3.100:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?real_stream`

Comment: Can you post the output you get when running those commands? in particular, the error output that is printed on failure?

Comment: for 2) - only lines marked in red are copied :

[6b002ce8] core access warning: connection timed out
[6b002ce8] access_realrtsp access error: cannot connect to 192.168.3.100:554
[6b002ce8] core access error: Connection failed
[6b002ce8] core access error: VLC could not connect to "192.168.3.100:554".
[6b002ce8] access_realrtsp access debug: could not connect to: 192.168.3.100:554/user=admin

Comment: continue:
[6b002ce8] core access debug: no access modules matched
[6b500510] core input error: open of `rtsp://192.168.3.100:554/user=admin' failed
[6b500510] core input error: Your input can't be opened
[6b500510] core input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://192.168.3.100:554/user=admin'. Check the log for details.

Comment: for 1)
[6b602d38] core access debug: looking for access module matching "rtsp": 24 candidates
[6b602d38] core access debug: net: connecting to 192.168.3.118 port 10554
[6b602d38] core access warning: connection timed out
[6b602d38] access_realrtsp access error: cannot connect to 192.168.3.118:10554
[6b602d38] core access error: Connection failed
[6b602d38] core access error: VLC could not connect to "192.168.3.118:10554".
[6b602d38] access_realrtsp access debug: could not connect to: 192.168.3.118:10554/udp/av0_0
[6b602d38] core access debug: no access modules matched

Comment: continue:
[6b500510] core input error: open of `rtsp://admin:kupelu9e@192.168.3.118:10554/udp/av0_0' failed
[6b500510] core input error: Your input can't be opened
[6b500510] core input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://admin:kupelu9e@192.168.3.118:10554/udp/av0_0'. Check the log for details.
[010dfed8] core playlist debug: dead input
[010dfed8] core playlist debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
[010dfed8] core playlist debug: nothing to play
[010dfed8] core playlist: end of playlist, exiting